# React Bootstrap ButtonToolbar Not Spacing Buttons Apart

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm having a problem keeping two buttons apart using the `ButtonToolbar` component in `react-bootstrap`. I would like these two buttons to be spaced apart, but I'm not sure what I need to do with the styling. According to the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/#button-toolbar), what I have done should be sufficient.

I've tried changing the className of `ButtonToolbar` to `justify-content-between` but that separates the buttons to both ends of the column.

[image]

```
          <ButtonToolbar style={{ marginTop: "17.5px" , }}>
            <Button
              size="sm"
              onClick={() => {
                setUndoPlayToggle(!undoPlayToggle);
                setPauseVariable(true);
              }}
              disabled={pitchStateLogs.length === 0}
            >
              Undo Play
            </Button>
            <Button size="sm">View Stats</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You would simply add a class margin (`mr-2`) to the left button:**

Or pick any [bootrap margin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) of your choice from 0 to 5:

```
<ButtonToolbar style={{ marginTop: "17.5px" }}>
  <Button
    size="sm"
    className="mr-2"
    onClick={() => {
      setUndoPlayToggle(!undoPlayToggle);
      setPauseVariable(true);
    }}
    disabled={pitchStateLogs.length === 0}
  >
    Undo Play
  </Button>
  <Button size="sm">View Stats</Button>
</ButtonToolbar>;
```

Live working example:

[image: Edit React bootstrap demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks @RyanLe. Just what I needed, hadn't realised you had to add the spacing to the buttons individually.

Comment: This is one of many ways you can add spacing to the button, which could also be using flex, gird or a few other ways.